# Double centralizer of derived subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be (finite) matabelian group; define $W(G):=C_G(C_G(G'))$; $G'$ is derived subgroup of $G$.

If $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of all maximal abelian normal subgroups of $G$ which contain $G'$, then for any $A\in\mathcal{F}$, it is easy to show that   $C_G(A)=A$. Since $G'\le A$, so $C_G(G')\ge C_G(A)=A$, so $C_G(C_G(G'))\le C_G(A)=A$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$; hence $$W(G)=C_G(C_G(G'))\le \bigcap_{A\in\mathcal{F}} A. $$

**Q.1** Is there non-nilpotent metabelian group where $W(G)$ is proper subgroup of intersection of all maximal abelian normal subgroups in $G$?

**Q.2** In metabelian groups $G$, what properties about $W(G)$ are known? Is there special name to this subgroup?

---

In the case of nilpotent groups, one can easily obtain example of this nature: take a $p$-group $H$ in which $H'$ is proper in $Z(H)$. Then $W(H)=Z(H)$; so to push $W(H)$ properly in intersection of all maximal abelian normal subgroups, we may look for a $p$-group in which maximal abelian normal subgroup is unique. I think, the construction of such $p$-group is not difficult; however, I was unable to find an example of non-nilpotent group.

---

**Edit** (after comment by Holt): I think, question (1) is not meaningful with following computation:

Let $G$ be (finite) metabelian; let $A_1,\ldots, A_l$ be all the maximal abelian normal subgroups containing $G'$. (So, $G/A_i$ is abelian, and it can be seen that $C_G(A_i)=A_i$.)

Suppose $g\in C_G(G')$. Note that $G'$ is abelian (since $G$ is metabelian). Then $\langle g,G'\rangle$ is  abelian *normal* subgroup of $G$ (since it contains $G'$), so $\langle g,G'\rangle\subseteq A_i$ for some $i$, hence $g\in A_i$ for some $i$. This means, $C_G(G')\subseteq \cup_i A_i$. Then taking centralizer in $G$, we get $C_G(C_G(G'))\supseteq \cap_i C_G(A_i)=\cap_i A_i$. Thus $W(G)\supseteq \cap A_i$. The reverse inclusion is shown before Q.1. Thus, for finite metabelian equality holds in equation before Q.1. (I hope this is correct. Comments will be helpful.)

Comment: I am sceptical about your claim that we can find $p$-groups in which the maximal abelian normal subgroup is unique. If $M$ is the unique maximal ablian normal subgroup of $H$ with $H' < Z(H)$, then choose any $g \in H \setminus M$. Then $\langle Z(H),g \rangle$ is abelian and normal so contained in a maximal abelian normal subgroup distinct from $M$.

Comment: I edited answer, and (agree with your comments), I think, in non-p groups which are metabelian, we may not expect example of type in Q.1.